# Print all combination of a set after pairing consecutive numbers

Tags: algorithm

Question is such that given a set of numbers we have to write a recursive program which **prints all possible combination after pairing consecutive numbers** or leaving them single.

---

```
<div>
Ex set 1,2,3,4,5,6
Output
<ul>
  <li>1,2,3,4,5,6</li>

  <li>12,3,4,5,6</li>
  <li>1,23,4,5,6</li>
  <li>1,2,34,5,6</li>
  <li>1,2,3,45,6</li>
  <li>1,2,3,4,56</li>

  <li>12,34,5,6</li>
  <li>12,3,45,6</li>
  <li>12,3,4,56</li>
  <li>1,23,45,6</li>
  <li>1,23,4,56</li>
  <li>1,2,34,56</li>

  <li>12,34,56</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use c++ to code.

Suppose the given set is a(a[0], a[1], ..., a[n - 1]), and the length of a is n
And the current answer is saved in b

```
void dfs(int pos, int depth)
{
    if(pos >= n)
        for(int i = 0; i < depth; ++i)
             printf("%d%c", b[i], i == depth - 1 ? '\n' : ',');
    else
    {
        b[depth] = a[pos];
        dfs(pos + 1, depth + 1);
        if(pos + 1 < n)
        {
             int c = 1, x = a[pos];
             while(x) c *= 10, x /= 10;
             b[depth] = a[pos] * c + a[pos + 1];
             dfs(pos + 2, depth + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call dfs(0, 0)

Comment: If your answer is larger INTMAX, you can use long long or use string directly